# Why I can't use devise's helpers in coffeescript files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Why I can't use devise's helpers in coffeescript files. For instance I would like to do something like this:

```
$http.post '<%= new_user_session %>', $scope.user
```

In my controllers/login.coffee.erb so that I would not have to hardcode links in js code. But this does not work and return error

> undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_path'

Comment: I just found that using it like `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_user_session_path` does the trick but is it correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried including the methods in the sprockets context? (untested)

```
# config/initializers/sprockets.rb
Sprockets::Context.send :include, Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: Also what I should include in sprockets initializers so that I can use `form_authenticity_token` directly in coffee files?

Comment: @SET the csrf token is stored in the session, but also usually injected into the page in a metatag https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js